# How to list pages with thumbnails, adding a "current-item" class

Tags: navigation

I'm using `get_pages()` to create a custom navigation that lists pages with a link, title and thumbnail for each page. 
How can I add a "current-item" class to the item corresponding to the current page?

I'm using the following code:

```
<?php
    $our_pages = get_pages( array( 'sort_column' => 'menu_order' ) );
    foreach ($our_pages as $key => $page_item):
?>
    <div class="menu-item">
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink($page_item->ID)); ?>" class="menu-item-clicker"><span><?php echo $page_item->post_title ; ?></span></a>
        <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page_item->ID,'full'); ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The following does not display the class, but to illustrate what I'm trying to do, here's the conditional I tried, with no success:

```
<?php
    $our_pages = get_pages( array( 'sort_column' => 'menu_order' ) );
    foreach ($our_pages as $key => $page_item) :
        if($page->ID == $page_item->ID) {
            $class = 'current-item';
        }
?>
    <div class="menu-item <?php echo $class; ?>">
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink($page_item->ID)); ?>" class="menu-item-clicker"><span><?php echo $page_item->post_title ; ?></span></a>
        <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page_item->ID,'full'); ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Looking forward to your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By `$page->ID`, I guess you're trying to fetch `ID` of the current page, right? If so, that's incorrect. Page itself is a **post type** so you need to get the ID through `$post->ID` and make sure `$post` is accessible otherwise use `get_the_ID()` to return ID of the current post/page.

Final code:

```
<?php

$our_pages = get_pages( array( 'sort_column' => 'menu_order' ) );
foreach ($our_pages as $key => $page_item) :
    $class = '';
    if($post->ID == $page_item->ID)
        $class = 'current-item';

?>
    <div class="menu-item <?php echo $class; ?>">
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink($page_item->ID)); ?>" class="menu-item-clicker">
            <span><?php echo $page_item->post_title ; ?></span>
        </a>
        <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page_item->ID,'full'); ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an additional info regarding the answer from @Junaid Ahmed:

You might add this **before** calling `$post->ID`:

```
global $post;
```

Comment: I guess, this is a comment to my question, so it should go as a comment. And I did mention in my answer "**make sure $post is accessible otherwise use `get_the_ID()`**"

Comment: You are right. It's just that I don't have the previleg to comment others peoples answers - missing repution right now. I tried. For your example is 99% complete I thought to post the missing 1%. If you add that information to your answer I can delete my answer if you want me to.

Comment: No problem. I just added some to your reputation. You are near your 50 rep mark. Enjoy